# How to turn my brightness on my computer below the minimum?

Tags: laptop, display, themes, brightness

I have Windows 10 acer predator HELIOS 300 laptop. I'm on minimum brightness, with night mode on and dark theme plugins and dark theme on for everything on all websites. And it helps during the day but it's still sometimes too bright like on cloudy days. But once it gets darker it''s still too bright and it hurts my eyes. I have really sensitive eyes. I have tried using another light source to help balance things out, but that's not always convenient to me. Is there anyway to lower my brightness on my laptop?

One other alternative I've realized is if I unplug my laptop the screen gets dimmer. So I've been doing that, but it's still not enough. I don't know why my eyes are so sensitive. I got them checked a few weeks ago and I still have 20/20 vision. But the brightness hurts and makes my eyes ache.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wear sunglasses?

Comment: @DavidPostill woah i never thought about that one. maybe i should try that. thank you! I do have one pair of sunglassses

Comment: "the brightness hurts and makes my eyes ache" did you mention that to your optician during the eye test? What did he say?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yep she said that was normal when looking at screens for long periods of times. She suggested I just look away more frequently and I've been doing that. Doesn't seem like any logical treatment for more sensitive eyes.

Comment: Well I look at normal screens (no dark mode, but I have used F.Lux for the last 10 years or so). for more than 12 hours a day (and have done for probably 40 years) and I don't have that problem. And I've never heard of anybody else saying what you are experiencing is normal.

Comment: @DavidPostill well damn. I guess she said that to calm me down I suppose. A lot of doctors been doing that when there's no real treatment.

Comment: And my eyes are sensitive to bright sunlight. I have to wear sunglasses outdoors for a good a part of the year.

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for the insight. I'll look more into it.